replacing a battery in the Lenovo Ideapad 3
I'm replacing the battery for a Lenovo Ideapad 3. The label fine print seems to show the model is 15IML05. When I search for that part in an online marketplace 2 batteries show up.
45 Wh battery 5B10X02602
35 Wh battery 5B10W67165
I bought the 45Wh battery. Not only can it hold more charge (Watt-hours) but to my surprise it has a different shape and is bigger than the original which is the 35Wh battery.
The screw holes on the bigger battery line up with holes on the laptop if I remove an SSD caddy.  This suggests to me that the M.2 card is the standard SSD and the caddy is for an expansion drive and I am not using an expansion drive.
I am hesitating to install the bigger battery since the original is labelled
7.6 V and limited charging voltage 8.7 V
while the bigger battery is labelled
11.1 V and limited charging voltage 12.6 V
Is this battery actually compatible?
Addendum... I checked a Lenovo.com website and under ideapad 3-15IML05 Laptop - Type 81WB the 45 Wh battery shows up with the same part number 5B10X02602 so there is no contradiction here. Still it seems wrong to put in a part that is labelled with different voltages.

I don't think we can answer this. If you don't trust the published information you'll need to contact Lenovo support directly. It is not uncommon for laptops to have lower and higher capacity battery options, so that part doesn't surprise me.

“Is this battery actually compatible?” - It sounds like it doesn’t actually fit. A battery with higher voltage is fine. It’s amperage thats a problem. There are dozens of questions about replacement batteries so I won’t be submitting an answer

@music2myear can you please cite examples of laptops that have 2 battery options?

@music2myear Nevermind. I found one.  This product has 3 battery options. https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/laptops-ultrabooks/precision-7680-workstation/spd/precision-16-7680-laptop/s002p7680cavp and they are described as 3 cell, 4 cell, and 6 cell. There is no indication of whether the cells are in series.

With all but the cheapest laptops I've used over the years, even for fully internal batteries, I've found they are offered with multiple battery options. Going back more than 20 years, the HP DV1000 I bought had two battery options. I bought the bigger one, and after heavy modification I was able to get Windows XP to run for 8+ hours even watching DVDs (yay for LOTR extended edition on long flights). These have always produced the same current, just storing far more energy that supported use for longer times.

@music2myear yeah but as an electronics hobbyist from years back I am reflexively averse to using a power source that is labelled 11.1 V when it is a replacement for one that is labelled 7.6 V.  I am not alone in this.  I posted essentially the same inquiry on electronics.stackexchange.com and 2 people each with over 40k reputation were against the idea of installing the higher voltage battery and the Q got forced closed by the stackexchange.

@music2myear multiple battery options with additional cells in parallel is something a person might reflexively be enthusiastic about.  with cells in series is a different matter.

You are better versed in this than many. Even as an experienced computer technician, and a one-time Ham radio operator, I know a bit about electrical theory, but I wouldn't grasp the significance of the difference. Having someone from Lenovo affirm (or correct) the purpose of this larger battery still seems to be the best way to get some real data, though, with your experience, you may be better able to answer this than the sort of technical contact you're likely to get at a large computer brand.

@music2myear In a repost I phrased my inquiry differently and some fairly high rep people are implying that laptops accept a range of DC volts because they are saying the batteries for a given model supply different voltages. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716222/are-these-cells-likely-to-be-in-series-or-parallel-or-both/716227#comment1905427_716227

@music2myear I don't consider this matter a judgement call.  Either it is a definite "no"
by default or a definite "yes" by design.  Unfortunately if sales material says "Watt-hours" and "mA-hours" and "A-hours" nobody really knows what's going on with voltage unless they do a little research.
